# header not work shows error header already sent

Tags: php, header

I used header function to sent session values to another page but when I used this code is shows headers already sent. I also don't give any blank spaces before starting code and ending code.

`Sample1.php`

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    if ($_REQUEST['uname'] == "vikas")
    {
    $_SESSION['us'] = $_REQUEST['uname'];
    header("location:Sample2.php");
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Invalid Data";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use the formatting option of the editor to make your post more in readable format.

Comment: Not Working Sir